# LSB Script: how do i know if something goes wrong?

Tags: debian, lsb

How do I know if a LSB script fails to load or where do I check the log of the lsbs scripts?

I added two scripts with the following command:

```
update-rc.d scriptname defaults
```

And just one launches the things I need. It does not seem to be a script error since if I launch it with /etc/init.d/scriptname it works.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nodes
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts all node apps
# Description:       Starts all node apps like AAM, AMT,...
### END INIT INFO

echo "Launch Node applications with forever"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Starts the redis server
redis-server

# Starts AAM
forever -o /var/log/AAM.log -e /var/log/AAM.log --spinSleepTime 2000 -m 5 start /var/nodejs/AAM/app.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will see when it boots on the screen.
2. Look in /varlog/sysylog or /var/log/messages
3. You can redirect your application output to a log file (you need to modify the script)

   forever -o /var/log/AAM.log -e /var/log/AAM.log --spinSleepTime 2000 -m 5 start /var/nodejs/AAM/app.js > /var/log/AAM_start.log 2>&1

Comment: I can not see what happens on boot since I log in using ssh..
nothing is logged on either of them (var/log/messages + syslog).
Anyway it worked by adding the log, thanks ^^

Comment: I'm glad it worked :)